# swift class can't call a oc method A but B is ok

Tags: ios, swift

in obj-c class have two method

```
+ (void)getContectListCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *array))completion;

+ (void)getInfoWithUserID:(NSString *)userid completion:(void (^) (ESUserDetailInfo *userInfo))completion;
```

but when i use this method in swift class there only one tip "`getContectlistComletion`"

[image]

Comment: You can do better than trusting Xcode's autocomplete. It's often spotty

Comment: Please show more related code.

Comment: Yeah, it would help if you show the related code

Comment: please review your question again, there were some conflicting edits and im not sure if ive deciphered the code correctly

Comment: Are you sure both methods are static?

Comment: Don't mind about autocompletion. Just type it and it will compile. Xcode has this kind of disadvantage - it poorly autocompletes static functions.